# Personalization Rules Being Ignored In Experience Editor

Tags: xdb, personalization

I am setting up personalization on my site (Sitecore 8.2 Update 2).

I have set up rules, pattern cards, etc. but apparently have something wrong.

In Sitecore Experience Editor, I see:

[image]

Yeah, you have detected my pattern card correctly!

But yet, the personalization that is setup under Presentation Details seems to be ignored?

[image]+

Why the disparity and how do I correct this issue?

Comment: Did you visit at least 4 pages that have profile info on it? There is a setting in the Sitecore.Analytics.config defining how many pages before pattern/profile tracking works with personalization. <setting name="Analytics.Patterns.MinimalProfileScoreCount" value="3" />

Comment: Are you saying the rules are being ignore while you are _**in**_ the Experience Editor?

Comment: @RichardSeal, I am Experience "Explorer" mode.

Comment: @ChrisAuer I have visited over five now, but same thing.

Comment: Assuming the order above is the order they are defined in, that's probably not the issue. Analyzing `Sitecore.Analytics.Rules.Conditions.ContactPatternMatchCondition` it looks to check the state of the `Tracker.Current/Session/Contact`.  Are there any relevant errors in the logs?

Comment: I opened a Sitecore Support ticket on this.   Working with @vandsh I am able to see that my code does return true, but for some reason personalization just falls through to the "Default" rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response that this is a bug in Sitecore.

*The issue happens due to the Experience Explorer executes the conditions at the time when the contact is already released. The experience explorer processors are executed on the HttpRequestEnd event and the contact is released on HttpRequestProcessed event, which happens earlier.*

Contact Sitecore Support if you are experiencing this issue and need the patch file.  The reference number for this patch is: 70639